# cakephp, validation checking a value in a separate table

Tags: mysql, validation, cakephp

I'm trying to create a site where, when we send an invoice, the relationship between sender and receiver must be active. This is done in a separate table and requires a boolean value of 1 in the other table.

The invoice will be saved in the table `invoices` with the following structure:

```
id
sender
receiver
amount
date due
```

the `relationship` table has the following structure:

```
id
partyone
partytwo
active
```

`partyone` and `partytwo` reference the users table.

The `users` table has the following structure:

```
id
username
password
```

What I'm trying to see is, if the relationships table contains partyone and partytwo AND the boolean is equal to one.

This is the function I have in my invoice table to add a new invoice. It can't be added to the database before a user is in an active relationship with that user.

```
public function addinvoice(){
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Invoice->create();
    if (0 === $this->relationship->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('activate'=>1,'relationship'=> $relationship)))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, you do not have an active relationship.');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    if ($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');
    }
} else { 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple answer to your question.

Modify your find like this:

```
$relationship = $this->relationship->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'partyone' => $user_one_id,
        'partytwo' => $user_two_id,
    ),
));

if (!$relationship) {
    //Error here
} else {
    //Save here
}
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, can you please select it as the correct answer?